# The energy of the photon $hf$, so what is the energy of other masses such as the Earth?

Tags: energy, electromagnetic-radiation, photons, frequency

The energy of the photon $hf$, so what is the energy of other masses, and of course I do not mean to write in frequency $f$, what is the relationship of the energy of other masses

Answer (score 2):

The energy of an object is related to its mass $m$ and its momentum $p$ by the equation:

$$ E^2 = p^2c^2 + m^2c^4 $$

This applies to all objects whether they have a mass or whether they are massless like photons. So this is the equation that you asked for.

If the object is stationary its momentum is zero, i.e. $p = 0$, and the equation becomes:

$$ E = mc^2 $$

which I'm sure you recognise as Einstein's well known equation relating mass and energy. If the object is massless like a photon, i.e. $m = 0$, the equation becomes:

$$ E = pc $$

To go any further we need to know that for any object the momentum is related to the [de Broglie wavelength](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matter_wave) by $p = h/\lambda$, and substituting this into the above equation we get:

$$ E = \frac{hc}{\lambda} $$

and for a photon (not for massive particles) $c = f\lambda$ giving us the equation you started with:

$$ E = hf $$

and that's where the equation $E = hf$ comes from.

Comment: In other words for Earth also, $E=hf$.

Comment: @my2cts well the Earth is not a coherent object :-)

Comment: @my2cts The Earth is not massless.

Comment: @VincentThacker That's another fact.

Answer (score 0):

The formula $E=hf$ holds for any coherent state, enen for Earth if it were coherent. For an incoherent system such as Earth you will need $E=h \sum_i w_i f_i$ where $i$ runs over the individual coherent states and $w_i$ is the weight by which each coherent state contributes to the incoherent state, so $ E=h \bar f$.